# What's the best practice when handling form submissions

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my Symfony2 app, I have actions handling form submissions. In an effort to clean up my controllers, I want to know where is the best place to do something like the following, or if the controller is the right place to handle the form and validate it.

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();
    $articleForm = $this->createForm(
        'web_article_type',
        $article
    );
    $articleForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($articleForm->isValid()) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($article);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('web_article_show'));
}
```

Comment: to handle form submission controller is good and for validation you can [Symfony Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) in which you define required rules in validation file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already the best practice form!

The Controller is the correct place for it because it handels the data that comes from the frontend. Also it renders a template if the form got errors or fires other actions if the form is valid.

I'd only get away from that way in the following case:

You have a form that should be extended with different fields for different user roles/permissions.

Then I'd define that form as a service for better handling of the form and better design.